# Cropping Option For Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, ios8.3

I want to choose picture from album and taking by Camera. It code work well but I need to select only part of image means cropping of image set my imageView.

```
-(IBAction)chooseAlbum:(id)sender
{
    imagePicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagePicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.delegate=self;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(IBAction)takePicture:(id)sender
{
    imagePicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagePicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
{
     profileImageView.image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on the editing mode

```
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
```

Then in your delegate method use `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` key

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info {
    profileImageView.image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to just add property imagePicker.

```
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

However you can also use the following third party library if you want more control and pleasant effect/animation.
https://github.com/myang-git/iOS-Image-Crop-View